# "properties should not be accessed directly" issue during WooCommerce 3.0 checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, checkout

My log shows a lot of the following messages:

> order_total was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. This message was added in version 3.0.

and it repeats that message for every property on Order.

What is the cause of these messages and what should I do to rectify them?

Comment: WooCommerce 3.0 is a *MAJOR* update. You would do well to test it on a staging site before going live.

Answer (score 4):

WooCommerce 3.0 revamped their code to restrict the direct access of property, you can either change your code like below.

```
    $OrderID= ( WC()->version < '2.7.0' ) ? $order->id : $order->get_id();
    $shipping_country   = (  WC()->version < '2.7.0' ) ? $order->shipping_country : $order->get_shipping_country();
```

Or Update your plugins to WC3 compatible.

$order->property : $order->**get_**property();