# woocommerce notice product_type was called incorrectly . Product properties should not be accessed directly

Tags: woocommerce, product

I'm having this notice with all products on shop page after updating WooCommerce version to 3.0.

Notice: product_type was called
incorrectly
. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\oye\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4137

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This surely come from your custom code or from your active theme (also it can be a third party plugin involved in woocommerce). Version 3.0+ is a Mega Major version and a lot of allowed code is now deprecated. So you will have to test everithing. Also that new WooCommerce version have some bugs, just because it's a new release. You will better go backwards and wait some time. The best thing is to have a staging website for testing and debugging...

Comment: Please try below answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279193/getting-issue-with-woocommerce3-0-checkout-in-wordpress/43279792#43279792

Comment: **All Class Objects properties are not accessible anymore directly in WooCommerce 3.0+.** you have to use the getter or setter methods  instead. In your case you have to use `$product` with the WC_Product object [get_type](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_type) method this way: `$product->get_type();`...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The product_type property is deprecated. Use [get_type()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_type) to get internal type.

So you need to change this:

`$product->product_type;`

to this:

`$product->get_type();`

Comment: Thanks.. You saved my lots of time.

Comment: woocommerce shouldn't get too bloated, but definetly have better outputs about deprecated calls

Answer (score -2):

(in functions.php) tried editing the "Select Options" text in WooCommerce and it gave that error.

Rafawhs answer worked for me too. This: $product->get_type();